# How to reference the Site Collection URL inside the src attribute

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, css

I added a custom script to my "Style Library" folder under a site collection. The site collection URL is `http://servername/HR`. So to reference the script inside my master page I wrote the following:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/hr/Style%20Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" ></script>
```

Where I am manually referencing the `/hr/` inside the `src`, so can I make this more dynamic and get the site collection URL dynamically, so if I move the site collection to another URL the script will still get referenced?

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could always use a site collection token in your URL.

```
~sitecollection
```

[URLs and tokens in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If that don't work out for you, this blog post has a lot of great examples when working with masterpages and references. [Use Site Url in SharePoint](http://ethan-deng.blogspot.se/2013/06/use-site-url-in-sharepoint.html)

**Update**

Try using a scriptlink instead. I'm unsure if encoding is needed thought. Try to have a blank space instead of `%20` in `/Style%20Library/`.

```
<SharePoint:Scriptlink runat="server" Name="~sitecollection/Style%20Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" Language="javascript" />
```

Comment: can you adivce more on this ,, i wrote the following  src="~sitecollection/Style%20Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" ,, but it did not work

Comment: You have to use Sharepoint:Scriptlink as specified from user19952

Comment: @displayName seems this is long approach to follow.. now i use to add my original script "<script  type="text/javascript" src="/hr/Style%20Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" ></script>" just before the end of </body> inside my master page.. now if i place the updated script on this location nothing will happen (the script will not fire)...so where exactly i need to place this script now ?

Comment: as this script is intended to hide some components from my Tree view, so it is suppose to fire after all the scripts and DOM are rendered ,, so it can override the defualt behavior ..

Comment: @johnG, try "~sitecollection/Style Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" instead.

Comment: it will not work src="~sitecollection/Style Library/Custom JS/HideTreeViewFolder.js" as it will be looking for a location named "~sitecollection/"